# Preventing Division by Zero

Tags: ruby

numerator: Value being divided.

denominator: Divisor value.

method so far:

```
def calc_percentage(numerator, denominator)
  ((numerator/ (denominator.to_f.nonzero? || 1 )) * 100)
end
```

What are the bad practices you see in the code above?  How can I improve it or write it in a better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to me the bad thing is that the function produces an *unexpected behavior*.

You try to divide by `0`, it divides by `1`. Huh?

What I would do is throw an Argument Error Exception (or what ever other exception that you think is appropriate).

```
def calc_percentage(numerator, denominator)
  if denominator.to_f.nonzero
      then (numerator/ denominator.to_f) * 100
      else raise ArgumentError, "Denominator can not be 0.", caller
  end     
end
```

This way it produces something that is logic and consistent.

Comment: Notes: 1) This `nonzero` is a remnant of the original question? 2) is it using caller as third argument to `raise` idiomatic? 3) I don't like inline conditionals, but they fit nicely here :-)

Comment: @tokland about 1), Wel; since we don't have much context I went with what I thought was the expected behavior of a function with a denominator! 2) It might be idiomatic and could prolly be removed I'm not a  ruby guy, but still answered the question to the best of my ruby knowledge with how would I have done the same in any other language!. 3) I'll add it. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: about (2) I asked because I hadn't seen never before, not that I thought it was wrong :-) Seeing your edit, I'd definitely write it differently: using a `if` with `else`.

Comment: @tokland I took it from this interesting article http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_exceptions.html and thought it was nice to have the trace, and wasn't sure about default behavior in Ruby!

Answer (score 2):

Notes:

- `def calc_percentage`. Where do you have this method? or is it a "free function"? usually you'd put it as a method in your own module (i.e. `module MyMath`), or extend the existing module `Math` or even, for very general abstractions, add it to the class as a method (`Numeric#percentage`). Adding methods to existing module/classes (monkeypatching) is common in Ruby, but potentially dangerous.
- `def calc_percentage`: Drop this `calc`, it's redundant.
- Ruby follows [IEEE_754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), infinites are supported by default. Of course your requirements come first, but it's usually a good idea to go along with the philosophy of the language (in this case, allow infinity as a percentage value).

So I'd write:

```
module MyMath
  def self.percentage(numerator, denominator)
    (numerator / denominator.to_f) * 100.0
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, intresting info about IEEE_754, didn't know... I have this method in a helper module defined. In the app->helpers folder.

Comment: @user1899082: a Rails helper? Then I don't think it's the best place to put it, this method has nothing to do with views (if it returned a string with '%' it'd be different).